# How do programs shutdown windows?

Tags: windows, shutdown

Upon doing some looking through my computer, I found a program called shutdown.exe and another relevant one which I forgot (shutdown.exe.mui ?).
This brought forward a question.

**How** does a program shutdown?

How does it bypass `shutdown -a`? Would a program-issued shutdown not work if shutdown.exe is missing? If so, does this apply to the shutdown button on the start menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does a program shutdown?

It calls the Win32 API [ExitWindowsEx()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex) function, which does some Windows-version-dependent magic to ask the system components to turn off the computer. JdeBP has an article about [what happens next](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604093253/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html) (on Windows Vista/7/8).

(There are also [a few other](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/system-shutdown-functions) shutdown functions.)

> How does it bypass shutdown -a?

By not giving you any time to *run* `shutdown -a` in the first place. The shutdown begins immediately. (`shutdown -a` cannot abort a shutdown in progress; it can only cancel a scheduled one.)

> Would a program issued shutdown won't work if shutdown.exe is missing?

Yes. Practically all programs call the Win32 API functions directly.

In fact, programs [wouldn't have worked](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214202132/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2006/01/27/518214.aspx) for many users if they *did* use shutdown.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to how to stop a program from shutting down during my work! Thanks a lot!